# Magento 2 Rest API get order details from customer id

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am beginner on a magento rest api, I cannot see in the API files or docs on how to retrieve order details of customer from customer id.

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-REST-Web-API-How-can-I-obtain-all-of-the-Orders-for-a/td-p/94596

Please see this answer.

Comment: @ Ronak Chauhan Thanks it show option email address. I required order details from customer id

Answer (score 3):

In this link you have all the information:

https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/salesOrderRepositoryV1/salesOrderRepositoryV1GetListGet

This is an example working on Postman, if you need any help to make it work in php let me know ;)

[image]

[http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]={customer_id}&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]==](http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=customer_id&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=%7Bcustomer_id%7D&searchCriteria%5BfilterGroups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bcondition_type%5D==)

Comment: According to screenshot url  order count wrong. It show all order count not customer vise plz check

Comment: Ups....Sorry, just updated the screenshot, my mistake. On the red square you have to put your customer id ;)
This should work !

http://yoursite.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=349&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]==

Comment: Please if this solved your problem mark as answer :)

Comment: Don't mean to nag you but please, if this solved your issue mark it as answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Please find a script that is standolone and can be placed anywhere within your magento files, on my environment it is in the folder

```
<magento-root>/app/code/Mbs/OrderRepositoryExtension/shell/getlistordersbycustomerid.php 



<?php
    
    $path = __DIR__ . '/../';
    
    while (!file_exists($path. '/vendor/autoload.php') && $i++ < 15) {
        $path .= '../';
    }
    require ($path. '/vendor/autoload.php');
    
    $path = __DIR__ . '/../';
    $zendLibrary = 'vendor/zendframework/zend-http/src/';
    $i = 0;
    
    while (!file_exists($path. $zendLibrary . 'Headers.php') && $i++ < 15) {
        $path .= '../';
    }
    
    require_once $zendLibrary . 'Headers.php';
    require_once $zendLibrary . 'Request.php';
    require_once $zendLibrary . 'Response.php';
    
    
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    
    // \Magento\Webapi\Model\ServiceMetadata::getServicesConfig to debug the available webapi services
    $params = ['customer_id' => null];
    foreach ($argv as $arg) {
        if (preg_match("%^--(.*?)=(.*?)$%", $arg, $m)) {
            $params[$m[1]] = $m[2];
        }
    }
    
    if (!$params['customer_id'])
        exit("Specify customer id (as --customer_id=_ID_ parameter)\n");
    
    $customer_id = $params['customer_id'];
    
    $token = 'or7ozb3e97x19nk97zylmhspul7niqi3';
    $httpHeaders = new \Zend\Http\Headers();
    $httpHeaders->addHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ]);
    
    $request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
    $request->setHeaders($httpHeaders);
    $request->setUri('http://magecertif.test/index.php/rest/V1/orders');
    $request->setMethod(\Zend\Http\Request::METHOD_GET);
    
    //searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=2020-06-28&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=gt&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=created_at&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=2020-06-29&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=lt
    
    $params = new \Zend\Stdlib\Parameters([
        'searchCriteria' => [
            'filterGroups' => [
                0 => [
                    'filters' => [
                        0 => [
                            'field' => 'customer_id',
                            'value' => $customer_id,
                            'condition_type' => 'eq'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            'current_page' => 1,
            'page_size' => 10
        ],
    ]);
    
    $request->setQuery($params);
    
    $client = new \Zend\Http\Client();
    $options = [
        'adapter'   => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl',
        'curloptions' => [CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true],
        'maxredirects' => 0,
        'timeout' => 30
    ];
    
    $client->setOptions($options);
    
    $response = $client->send($request);
    
    echo $response->getBody();
```

to call this script: open a terminal and at the root of your magento install, hit `php <script_location>/getlistordersbycustomerid.php --customer_id=1`

on my environment: `php app/code/Mbs/OrderRepositoryExtension/shell/getlistordersbycustomerid.php --customer_id=1`

Comment: @ Herve Tribouilloy plz suggest name file saved in my root folder

Comment: please share rest api  url for get customer order details from customer id

Comment: please share api url to get order details from customer id

Comment: answer is updated

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the below code. You need to pass customer id in API

Below are the module details with file.

Step-1: Create registration file **Pushpendra/CustomerOrder/registration.php**

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Pushpendra_CustomerOrder',
        __DIR__
    );
```

Step-2: Create a module file  **Pushpendra/CustomerOrder/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Pushpendra_CustomerOrder" setup_version="1.0.0" />
    </config>
```

Step-3: Create a webapi.xml file like below path  **Pushpendra/CustomerOrder/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/customer/order/:id" method="GET">
        <service class="Pushpendra\CustomerOrder\Api\CustomerOrderInterface" method="getList"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Step-4: Create a file for API **Pushpendra/CustomerOrder/Api/CustomerOrderInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace  Pushpendra\CustomerOrder\Api;


interface CustomerOrderInterface
{
    /**
     * Returns orders data to user
     *
     * @api
     * @param  string $id customer id.
     * @return return order array collection.
     */
    public function getList($id);
}
```

Step-5: Create a file CustomerOrder.php like below path **Pushpendra/CustomerOrder/Model/CustomerOrder.php**

```
<?php
    namespace  Pushpendra\CustomerOrder\Model;    
    
    
    use Pushpendra\CustomerOrder\Api\CustomerOrderInterface;
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
    
    class CustomerOrder implements CustomerOrderInterface
    {
        private $order;
        /**
         * CustomerOrder constructor.
         *
         * @param Order $order
         */
        public function __construct(
            Order $order
        ) {
            $this->order = $order;
        }
    
        /**
         * Returns orders data to user
         *
         * @api
         * @param  string $id customer id.
         * @return return order array collection.
         */
        public function getList($id)
        {
            $order = $this->order->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $id);
            $data=[];
            $i=0;
            foreach ($order as $orderDetails) {
                $data[$i]['increment_id']=$orderDetails->getIncrementId();
                $data[$i]['created_at']=$orderDetails->getCreatedAt();
                $data[$i]['ship_to']=$this->getShipTo($orderDetails->getId());
                $data[$i]['grand_total']=$orderDetails->getGrandTotal();
                $data[$i]['status']=$orderDetails->getStatus();
                $data[$i]['id']=$orderDetails->getId();
                $i++;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    
       
    }
```

You need to call API by below example **magentourl/V1/customer/order/customerId**

Comment: please share proper module creation steps. I am beginner in Magento 2

Comment: @Gagan, Check updated answer

Comment: thanks for help. I follow all steps of module but show error when hit url 
 http://127.0.0.1/jodhpur/rest/V1/customer/order/723
Response show html code - 
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Vendor\Module\CustomerOrder\Api\CustomerOrderInterface in C:\wamp64\www\jodhpur\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 50

Comment: It was working. Let me check it again

Comment: Yes please check again. If possible please  share screenshot

Comment: @Gagan check updated answer, there was folder issue in the last answer. Now it's updated

Comment: @Gagan did you check

Comment: again check module but show same error
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Chirpn\CustomerOrder\Api\CustomerOrderInterface in C:\wamp64\www\jodhpurbkp\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 50