# Braintree PayPal error after upgrading magento version to 2.3.5

Tags: paypal, magento2.3.5, braintree

In my dev site I started getting the error in the image below after upgrading from 2.3.2 to 2.3.5.
[image]

```
code: "PAYPAL_SANDBOX_ACCOUNT_NOT_LINKED"

details: undefined

message: "A linked PayPal Sandbox account is required to use PayPal Checkout in Sandbox. See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/testing-go-live
```

In my main branch witch is still on the 2.3.2 version everything works well (it's pointing to the same braintree sandbox accounts). Any help is much appreciated. thanks !

Comment: looks like you may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50147503/paypal-integration-from-braintree-sandbox-error-paypal-sandbox-account-not-link

Comment: It worked !!! Please write this as an answer I'd like to give you credit for pointing me in the right direction !

Comment: Feel free to upvote this one https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316380/magento-2-rest-api-get-order-details-from-customer-id/316401#316401.. I admit I was hoping it would be accepted and I was feeling annoyed it didn’t :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should try to link your PayPal Sandbox account with Sandbox Braintree account.

Here are described steps -> [linked-paypal-testing](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/testing-go-live#linked-paypal-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Braintree doc: https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/testing-go-live#linked-paypal-testing

**You have to link your Paypal account to Braintree**

In order to link a [PayPal sandbox test account](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/sandbox/accounts/) to your Braintree sandbox account, you will need the API credentials for that PayPal sandbox test account.

If you don't already have a PayPal sandbox test account for testing your Braintree integration, create a new one by following these steps:

1. Create a PayPal business sandbox account:

   - Log into the [PayPal Developer Dashboard](https://developer.paypal.com/)
   - Navigate to Sandbox > Accounts
   - Click Create Account
   - Select the same Country as your Braintree sandbox account
   - Select the account type as Business
2. Go to the [Create New App](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create) page

   - Create an app to get sandbox API credentials
   - Select the same sandbox developer account as the test account created in step 1
3. Note the following Sandbox API Credentials for the new app you created:

   - Email address associated with this app
   - Client ID
   - Secret

Once you have those PayPal sandbox API credentials, enter them in your Braintree sandbox:

1. Log into your [Braintree sandbox Control Panel](https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login)
2. Navigate to Settings > Processing > Payment Methods > PayPal
3. Click Link Sandbox
4. Enter the Email address, Client ID, and Client Secret for your PayPal sandbox test account
5. Click Link PayPal Sandbox